# Whenever I run a apt command I get an error about libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' missing

Tags: package-management, libraries

From one day to another my Ubuntu 22.04 seems to be missing `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.29`

Since this error occurs on every `apt` command I could not install anything or even update my repos.

`strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX` gives me

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

I have `libstdc++6:amd64 10-20200411-0ubuntu1` installed

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the missing package manually.
For this go to https://packages.ubuntu.com/, select your Ubuntu version and search for libstdc++6 in this case. Then on https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libstdc++6 you need to select the right architecture (amd64 in my case) and copy the url of the link under `security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`.

Then you need to download and install this package:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-12/libstdc++6_12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04_amd64.deb
```

And finally run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`